# Can CMSampleBuffer decode H264 frames?

Tags: ios, h.264, core-media

Would someone be able to provide a quick yes or no answer to this question?  I am starting to feel there's a conspiracy from Apple to stop people using their hardware decoder for H.264.

The question:

Can you decode H.264 frames using the CoreMedia type CMSampleBuffer and its API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Cthutu  -  6 years later I am researching how to play raw, non-container H.264 video stream at 5 frames a second on ios.  I found this post and a few others, but no good answers yet - so I was wondering if you ever got anywhere on playing h.264 on ios?  If you had any links or pointers?

Comment: No I didn't because I've long left that job that dealt with that problem.  However, a year after I asked this question, I think iOS now exposed the private API that can decode single frames.  I can't tell you any more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use VideoToolbox to decompress H.264 video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream)