# Decoding h264 on ios

Tags: ios, h.264

This is based on the answer you provided for this thread.
[Can CMSampleBuffer decode H264 frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842812/can-cmsamplebuffer-decode-h264-frames)
Can you give more pointers , how you achieved it ?
I am getting a h264 raw stream from socket on my iphone. How to play it ?
hope you will give some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple doesn't give us direct access to the hardware, and there's no way (as far as I know) to just get the AVAssetReader to take raw h.264 data.  Perhaps somebody has figured it out and would be kind enough to shed some light on it for us.

So the other solution would be to write it to an MP4 file on disk, or switch to HLS as your streaming method.  You could also switch to a software decoder.  That would solve your problem but give you a new problem in that it will eat up a lot of CPU resources if you're doing HD at a high frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with FFMPGE or VideoToolKit framework provided by Apple Inc.